# Find sign change in array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have data in excel which starts with negative values, passes zero and reaches a certain positive value. I put this particular set of data in an array `dataset1 = {-9.5,-7,-5.25,-3,-1.1,0,1,5,20,50}` (just as an example, the values aren't linearly spaced) to do some calculations. But what I need to know is the index of the last number which has a sign (is negative).
How can I do that? Sadly there is no function like `IsSigned(..)=true`.

Comment: And checking whether a number is less than zero doesn't help?

Comment: Derp Derp. Maybe I was staring at the screen for too long today -.-'. Stupid me.

Comment: Thanks by the way ;-D. Going to be now.

Comment: Everybody's had a day like that at some point. We understand.

Comment: There is also the `Sgn()` function that returns `-1`, `0` or `+1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it without a loop

```
Sub test()

    Dim dataset1 As Variant

    dataset1 = Array(-9.5, -7, -5.25, -3, -1.1, 0, 1, 5, 20, 50)

    Debug.Print UBound(Filter(dataset1, "-")) + 1

End Sub
```

Comment: Good reminder of the function Filter! Note to OP: this will only work if the array is really sorted.

Comment: Thanks for the hint and the solution.

Answer (score 0):

My solution looks like this:

```vb
'Find last signed value
 For i = LBound(concarraycleared, 2) To UBound(concarraycleared, 2)
     If concarraycleared(2, i) < 0 Then
         LastSignedIndex = i
     Else
         Exit For
     End If
 Next i
```

Couple of limitations: Array needs to be vertical, can only find the last signed value one time, values need to be sorted in ascending order. You can not reverse search order. This is pretty specific solution tailored to my problem, so the above solution should be regarded fist.